# When updating a ListView of CheckBox items, is it better to update the individual view, or notifyDataSetChanged() and invalidateViews()?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, view, listviewitem

Both of these work, but is one better than the other?

Update individual view:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
    MyObject item = (MyObject) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i);
    boolean isChecked = item.isChecked();
    item.setChecked(!isChecked);
    ((CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox)).setChecked(!isChecked);
}
```

Update all views:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
    MyObject item = (MyObject) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i);
    item.setChecked(!item.isChecked());
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    getListView().invalidateViews();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Updating individual view is bad, because `findViewById` take a long time (vs other methods) to execute and because there will be a case when you want to update a lot of list items (say, 20 items). You will not want to update your items one by one - it will take a lot of time and resources.

Now, take a look at your code when updating all items :

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
    MyObject item = (MyObject) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i);
    item.setChecked(!item.isChecked());
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    getListView().invalidateViews(); //you can remove this line, read my explanation below
}
```

You called `notifyDataSetChanged` and `invalidateViews`, which is a waste in your case. Why?

notifyDataSetChanged will refresh the `listview` if an item's **value/data** has been changed.

Example : `checkbox's` value changed - like in your case.

Meanwhile, invalidateViews will refresh the `listview` if an item's **properties** has been changed.

Example : `textview's` color or text size changed.

Hence, in your case there is no need to call `getListView().invalidateViews();` because no item's properties is changed, the one and only that changed is item's value/data.

**UPDATE BY REQUEST :**

This is an example where you should (and only need to) call `invalidateViews` :

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
    MyObject item = (MyObject) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i); //lets say item is TextView
    item.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    item.setTextSize(2);    
    item.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
    getListView().invalidateViews();
}
```

Because `setTextSize`, `setBackgroundColor`, and `setTextColor` just change **properties**, not value/data.

Comment: Thanks. Can you give me an example of an item property (where I would want to use `invalidateViews()`)?

Comment: @BLuFeNiX Done :) Feel free to ask if u still have question